# Replace text using regex in RAD Studio

Tags: regex, delphi

I want to replace for example **F(G(X,Y));** with **H(X,Y);** In RAD Studio IDE.

The regex I use is:

Find Expression: `F\(G\((.+)\)\);`
Replace Expression: `H($1)`

The result is not as I expect:

Result: `H($1)`

It seems the RAD Studio does not recognize the $1 as the contents between two parentheses.

Anybody have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the docs? They will tell you the correct syntax.

Comment: Yes, I have read the docs, and found nothing in this case.

Comment: You didn't look hard enough. It's here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Regular_Expressions  From the IDE you can just press F1 in the replace dialog!  Trying to guess regex syntax without reading the docs is pointless.

Comment: I have seen this link, as you see there is nothing about how to replace the group, Not $1 nor \1 will help. see my below comment.

Comment: No, it's right there in the link. You just have to read it all carefully. _Braces group characters or expressions. Groups can be nested, with a maximum number of 10 groups in a single pattern. For the Replace operation, groups are referred to by a backslash and a number, according to the position in the "Text to find" expression, beginning with 0. For example, given the text to find and replacement strings, Find: {[0-9]}{[a-c]*}, Replace: NUM\1, the string 3abcabc is changed to NUMabcabc._

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use {} to group the expression rather than () and \1 in the replacement text:

Find Expression: `F\(G\({.+}\)\)`; Replace Expression: `H(\0)`

Comment: Thank you, the "H(\1)" should become "H(\0)" (Zero base)