# Using Regex to replace string in Delphi

Tags: regex, delphi

From [Official documentation of RegularExpressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Regular_Expressions), the output should be `NUMabcabc`. But it is not. I wonder what is wrong ?

```
program Project128;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses RegularExpressions;

var Regex: TRegEx;
begin
  Regex := TRegEx.Create('{[0-9]}{[a-c]*}');
  WriteLn(Regex.Replace('3abcabc', 'NUM\1'));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you want to post an answer containing the correct code, see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for information about how to do so properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the wrong docs. The docs you reference are for the regex flavour used by IDE search and replace. That flavour of regex is just used by the IDE. The flavour used by the `RegularExpressions` unit is PCRE, which is quite different and is documented [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help! (I took the comments and link from this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488751 without realizing it is related to IDE ... :D)