# CharInSet bulk conversions when migrating from Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, unicode, migration, delphi-xe8

We are shifting a number of projects from Delphi 2007 to XE8 and have a number of the following warning (many hundreds of them):

```
[dcc32 Warning] X.PAS(1568): W1050 WideChar reduced to byte char in set expressions.  Consider using 'CharInSet' function in 'SysUtils' unit.`
```

It occurs to me that many of these are of the form

```
if x in ['1','2','3'] then
```

which need to be converted to

```
if CharInSet(x, ['1','2','3']) then
```

And this looks like there might be some sort of regular expression type search and replace that could be used to do these in bulk.

Can anyone think of a way to convert these in bulk?

Comment: This would be a nice refactoring to write as an IDE Expert, maybe contribute it to GExperts.  I think rather than using regular expressions, using a parser like the Castalia parser would make more sense. After all any use of "x in y" where type of x is Char and y is a set of char, literal or not, could benefit from the refactoring.

Comment: I'm yet to be convinced that `CharInSet` is the way forward

Comment: But yes, you could write a regex to catch these. Why not try to do just that? What's holding you back. Write a regex to find these uses of in. Test that it finds only instances that need to be changed. Then use capture to perform the replacements. Many tools are available. Review carefully before committing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, last time I checked (XE8) `CharInSet` performance, it was surprisingly well optimized.

Comment: @LURD The last time I checked 2009-10Seattle the performance of CharInSet was still much slower if you have a constant set because CharInSet always uses the memory bit operations while "element in set" can use arithmetic operations without memory access for constant sets.  BTW: The compiler generates the same code for `if c in ['a'..'z'] then stmt` and `case c of 'a'..'z': stmt; end;`. As long as you don't have non-ascii chars in your set, the `c in charset` is still valid. Only the wide-char warning must be disabled.

Comment: Disabling warning seems safe to me.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen, thanks, using case seems like the best option if you don't want the warnings.

Comment: @WarrenP But only if you have checked if all the code doesn't use non-ascii chars. So if you have migrated pre-unicode code you should really check first before disabling warnings.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with *Search/Replace* in the IDE.

The following works for me in **XE4**.

- search for:

  ```
  if {[a-z]} in \[{{'[0-9]+'\,? ?}+}\] then
  ```

  If you want to match a variable more than one character long, consider to use some quantifier like `[a-z]+`.
- replace with:

  ```
  if CharInSet\(\0, \[\1\]\) then
  ```

Notice that the IDE uses `{}` for groups and `\0`, `\1` ... as replacement placeholders.

[Embarcadero Regular Expressions reference for Delphi XE4](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Regular_Expressions)

---

IDE *regular expressions* search:

[image: IDE regex search]

The resulting unit:

[image: IDE regex search replaced]

---

You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488751/replace-text-using-regex-in-rad-studio) useful for further reference.